# Automatic screenshots with selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Is there anyway function that will insert a capture screenshot function after every page event, such as pageload or selecting a dropdown. currently I am using selenium html files and feeding those to selenium rc but have to manually insert screenshots after every command. and if i edit the script i have to edit the screenshots again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `captureEntirePageScreenshot(String fileName, "")`

filName should be absolute path of file location say "C:/foo/bar.png"

Better way would be to create a base folder and generate a string everytime you have to caputre screenshot

```
`captureEntirePageScreenshot(rootFolder+"/"+generatedString+".png","")
```

this works very well in firefox 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I couldn't find a way to do this exactly, but I got around it by spawning a new thread at the start of each test that took a screen shot every half second, and killed that thread in the teardown.